# Decreasing Runtime of Scipy Statistical Computations

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numpy-ndarray, scipy.stats

I have a 2-D Numpy array with a shape 2500, 200, where Scipy is to compute statistics (gamma CDF specifically) at each entry in the array. I've provided a random generation of floating point numbers for those aiming to run the code locally, note that the data in this array must be expressed as decimals. The code is as follows:

```
def gcdfstats(inputarr):
    if all(x==inputarr[0] for x in inputarr):
        value = 0
    else:
        param = sci.stats.gamma.fit(inputarr)
        x = np.linspace(0, int(np.round(np.max(inputarr), 0)), int(np.round(np.divide(np.max(inputarr), 0.01), 0)))
        cdf = sci.stats.gamma.cdf(x, *param)
        value = np.round((sci.stats.gamma.cdf(1.25, *param) * 100), 2)
    return value
    
def getrow_stats():
    # Generate A Random Sample of Numbers (2,500 Entries, 200 Values Each) in Float Precision
    inputarr = np.random.uniform(0.00, 8.00, (2500,200))
    # Compute Gamma CDF For Each
    outstats = [gcdfstats(entry) for entry in inputarr]
    return outstats
```

Upon running this across the array, I'm noticing what I believe to be subpar speeds in computing these statistics at each array entry. After running this a total of 5 times on the server, I average 7-10 entries/CDF values completed a second, which is much too slow for larger datasets.

Despite not having a specific Numpy function that could be broadcast across this entire array at once, I've still taken specific steps to ensure the gcdfstats function runs quickly. This includes utilizing list comprehension in place of a for loop and Numpy ufuncs (max, divide, & round) where appropriate.

Are there any additional steps that can be taken to speed up the completion of this function?

Comment: AFAIK, `sci.stats.gamma.cdf` is not efficiently implemented. You can write your own implementation based on the SciPy code and Numba [like I did for `multivariate_normal.pdf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75841918/vectorizing-multivariate-normal-distribution-calculation/75844015#75844015). This should be substantially faster. Note that some functions are already implemented in [`numba-stats`](https://pypi.org/project/numba-stats/) but your target function does not seem to be implemented by this module.

Comment: This is good to know, your previous answer is a rather insightful starting point @JérômeRichard. So it appears I have to target the class gamma_gen(rv_continuous), is it possible to easily re-write this using Numpy/Numba? https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.10.1/scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py#L2989-L3149

Comment: I am confident this is possible but this is not easy nor fast to do that. I spent few hours to do that for the other similar function (with a similar code). I expect the resulting code to be significantly faster du to math operations being done in pure-python in the linked code. That being said, methods calls to the `optimize` module will be certainly difficult/tedious to convert. Good luck!

Comment: An alternative solution is to ask to the SciPy developers a vectorized implementation of such function since you are apparently not the only one to complain about the performance of such function. You can open an issue for that if there is none already (https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues). Unfortunately, I do not expect this to be done quickly since it is also a significantly work (and SciPy is an open source project with already many open issues).

Comment: I've done an initial inspection of the some of the other module/methods calls, which all appear related to best-fitting for the gamma function. My assessment after a first pass is that isolating these methods and preparing all method/class interactions for strictly Numpy math operators (add, integrate, etc.) will speed this up dramatically?

Comment: This is hard to say. The calls to the `optimize` module methods might be the bottleneck, but I expect this this be very dependent of the input since optimization technics tends to use iterative approaches with a data-dependent convergence. I expect this to result in a reasonable speed-up (certainly >2x), but the best thing to do is to try.

Answer (score 1):

`stats.gamma.cdf` is quite fast. Timing snippets from your code reveals that `stats.gamma.fit` dominates the execution time:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
inputarr = np.random.uniform(0.00, 8.00, (200))
%timeit stats.gamma.fit(inputarr)
# 44.3 ms ± 2.82 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
param = stats.gamma.fit(inputarr)
x = np.linspace(0, int(np.round(np.max(inputarr), 0)), int(np.round(np.divide(np.max(inputarr), 0.01), 0)))
%timeit stats.gamma.cdf(x, *param)
# 206 µs ± 22.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
cdf = stats.gamma.cdf(x, *param)
%timeit np.round((stats.gamma.cdf(1.25, *param) * 100), 2)
# 136 µs ± 17.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

This is because when the location of the distribution is free, `stats.gamma.fit` relies on a [generic optimization routine](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/f990b1d2471748c79bc4260baf8923db0a5248af/scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py#L3315-L3319) to perform maximum likelihood estimation. Often, the gamma distribution is used without a location parameter (e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution)). If this is appropriate for your use case, you can fix the location at zero, and `fit` will be much faster.

```
%timeit stats.gamma.fit(inputarr, floc=0)
# 90.6 µs ± 54 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: This is very insightful, I appreciate the inspection of timing of each component in this. For the data I'm fitting to gamma curves, setting the location to zero is suitable, so I'll implement these suggestions to see how much faster this becomes.