# How to compute faster scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.cdf() a large number of times?

Tags: python, scipy, compiler-optimization, scipy.stats

what i'm trying to do is to compute a large number of times the cumulative normal distribution function. I'm only calling it on small instances (2 variables), but it is painfully slow. Here is how my code looks like so far :

```
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal

res = np.zeros((horizon,nb_groups,nb_ratings))
mean = [0,0]
mu = np.zeros((horizon,nb_groups,nb_ratings))
sigma = np.ones((horizon,nb_groups,nb_ratings))
rho = np.ones((horizon,nb_groups,nb_ratings)) #in the actual code rho,mu, sigma do not contain only ones and zeros but it doesnt really matter here

horizon,nb_groups,nb_ratings = 50,3,8
for t in range(horizon):
    for g in range(nb_groups):
        for i in range(nb_ratings):
            if thresh[t,g,i]==float('-inf'):
                res[t,g,i]=0
            else:
                res[t,g,i] = multivariate_normal(mean=mean,cov=[[1,rho[t,g,i]],[rho[t,g,i],1]]).cdf([mu[t,g,i]/np.sqrt(1+sigma[t,g,i]**2),thresh[t,g,i]])
```

i've done some tests and what makes it so slow is the use of nested for loops, and if i could vectorize the computations the whole process would be much faster, as showed here :

this is the test setup:

```
import random
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm, multivariate_normal as mvn

n = 1000000

inputs1 = np.array([random.uniform(-100, 100) for _ in range(n)])
inputs2 = np.array([random.uniform(-100, 100) for _ in range(n)])
inputs3 = np.array([np.array([random.uniform(-100, 100),random.uniform(-100, 100)]) for _ in range(n)])
```

```
mean = [0,0]
cov = [[1,0.5],[0.5,1]]
bivariate = mvn(mean, cov)

for i in range(n):
    a = bivariate.cdf([inputs1[i],inputs2[i]])
```

runs in around 3mins

but `a = bivariate.cdf(inputs3)` runs in under 9 seconds

My problem being that i didnt manage to apply the same vectorization process as shown in the tests because my covariance matrices changes at each call. Have you some ideas how I could make it faster/vectorize it ?

Comment: i also tried to use just in time compilation with the numba package by recoding the cdf computation but didnt really manage to make it work

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75841918/vectorizing-multivariate-normal-distribution-calculation . The alternative is indeed the Scipy numba package which is experimental and only implement few functions so far (not to mention it is also a less efficient solution).

Answer (score 0):

Looping is slow in this case because the `cdf` method has a lot of overhead. You can avoid the overhead by directly calling the (private) function that computes the CDF.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal as mvn, _mvn
rng = np.random.default_rng()

mean = np.zeros(2)
cov = np.asarray([[1, 0.5], [0.5, 1]])
n = 1000000
x = rng.uniform(size=(n, 2))

bivariate = mvn(mean, cov)
ref = bivariate.cdf(x)

# lower limit of integration
low = np.asarray([-np.inf, -np.inf])
# maxpts is the maximum number of points to evaluate the PDF
# abseps and releps try to control the absolute and relative error
options = dict(maxpts=None, abseps=1e-5, releps=1e-5)
# _mvn.mvnun returns a tuple; we want the 0th element
res = np.asarray([_mvn.mvnun(low, xi, mean, cov, **options)[0] 
                  for xi in x])

np.testing.assert_allclose(res, ref)
```

Note that `_mvn.mvnun` is private, so it can be changed without notice. (It probably *will* change within the next few years because a lot of old Fortran code is being replaced.)